# How enable remote console to my project (written in angular)?

Tags: node.js, angular6

In my application i want to open the terminal. like visual studio code,
if we open new project, terminal related to that path has to open.i am getting only terminal no commands working on it.

I used ng-terminal for terminal.but in that commands not working

```
app.componet.ts

import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgTerminalComponent } from 'ng-terminal';
import { NgTerminal } from 'ng-terminal/lib/ng-terminal';``

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
 title = 'ter';
@ViewChild(NgTerminalComponent) child: NgTerminal;

 ngAfterViewInit(){
/  /this.invalidate();
  this.child.keyInput.subscribe((input) => {
    this.child.write(input);
  })
 }

 }
  app.component.html

   <ng-terminal></ng-terminal>
```

Comment: please answer this question as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi Mulsa Prathap , Have you found any solution for this? I also need to implement such functionality, any help .

Comment: ng-terminal merely displays output in a special way. you need to send the input somewhere and then get the output from that place. we don't know what exactly you want to accomplish but it is probably not as simple as you think